# 550 Filename invalid when use ftp_fput in php

Tags: php, ftp

I try to use `ftp_fput` in PHP. It gives me an error like:

> 550 Filename invalid.

I am using code like this way:

```
// $ftp_conn is connection string.

// Generate temp file 
$temp = tmpfile();
fwrite($temp, $temp_css_data); // $temp_css_data = file data
fseek($temp, 0, SEEK_SET);

ftp_fput($ftp_conn, $dest, $temp, FTP_BINARY); // $dest is remote server path
// $dest = "D:/xampp/htdocs/sites/1890/style.css";
```

Destination path is proper because its create folder there but not put file into folder.

Comment: If you get "Filename invalid" back from the server it would make sense to include the filename you are trying to use into your question instead of just `$dest`.

Comment: $dest is "D:/xampp/htdocs/sites/1890/style.css";

Comment: If this works giving the full path including the windows drive name depends on the server. Try using `ftp_chdir` to change to the directory and then only put `style.css` inside the directory instead of the full path.

Comment: Show us a log file from a standalone FTP client proving that you can upload a file to `D:/xampp/htdocs/sites/1890/style.css`.

Comment: `code`if (@!ftp_chdir($ftp_conn, $path)) {
                if (@!ftp_mkdir($ftp_conn, $path))
                    return false;
            }
`code`//$path = "D:/xampp/htdocs/sites/1890/"
So its create directory first. Its work properly but then I upload file via above code its not work.